# Got Failed to decode JSON object when calling a POST request in flask python

Tags: python, json, flask, webserver, flask-restful

I have written a simple REST-ful web server in python with `flask` following steps in this [tutorial](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/designing-a-restful-api-with-python-and-flask); but I've got a problem calling `POST` request. The code is:

```
@app.route('/todo/api/v1.0/tasks', methods=['POST'])
def create_task():
    if not request.json or not 'title' in request.json:
        abort(400)
    task = {
        'id': tasks[-1]['id'] + 1,
        'title': request.json['title'],
        'description': request.json.get('description', ""),
        'done': False
    }
    tasks.append(task)
    return jsonify({'task': task}), 201
```

I send a `POST` request using `curl` as the example in the above mentioned page:

```
curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"title":"Read a book"}' http://127.0.0.1:5000/todo/api/v1.0/tasks
```

But I get this error in response:

```
HTTP/1.0 400 BAD REQUEST
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 187
Server: Werkzeug/0.11.10 Python/2.7.9
Date: Mon, 30 May 2016 09:05:52 GMT

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Failed to decode JSON object: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)</p>
```

I've tried to debug and I found out in the `get_json` method, the passed argument has been translated to `'\\'{title:Read a book}\\''` as `data` and `request_charset` is `None`; but I have no idea for a solution. Any help?

**EDIT 1:**

I have tried @domoarrigato's answer and implemented the `create_task` method as the following:

```
@app.route('/todo/api/v1.0/tasks', methods=['POST'])
def create_task():
    try:
        blob = request.get_json(force=True)
    except:
        abort(400)
    if not 'title' in blob:
        abort(400)
    task = {
        'id': tasks[-1]['id'] + 1,
        'title': blob['title'],
        'description': blob.get('description', ""),
        'done': False
    }
    tasks.append(task)
    return jsonify({'task': task}), 201
```

But this time I got the following error after calling `POST` via `curl`:

```
HTTP/1.0 400 BAD REQUEST
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 192
Server: Werkzeug/0.11.10 Python/2.7.9
Date: Mon, 30 May 2016 10:56:47 GMT

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.</p>
```

**EDIT 2:**

To clarify, I should mention that I'm working on a 64-bit version of Microsoft Windows 7 with Python version 2.7 and the latest version of Flask.

Answer (score 26):

This works in Windows 7 64:

```
curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d "{\"title\":\"Read a book\"}" http://localhost:5000/todo/api/v1.0/tasks
```

Back slashes and double quotes.

Comment: Worked for me! Using Windows 10 x64. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you @dmitriy-bogdanov This worked for me in Windows 10 - 64bit version...

Comment: Using powershell you will need to use ` to escape the double quote

Answer (score 4):

I Managed to get it working using Anaconda cmd window, python3, using backslashes and double quotes around the whole expression!
Works:

```
curl "localhost:5000/txion" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"from\": \"akjflw\" ,\"to\" : \"fjlakdj\", \"amount\": 4}"
```

Does not work:

```
curl "localhost:5000/txion" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{\"from\": \"akjflw\" ,\"`to\" : \"fjlakdj\", \"amount\": 4}'
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using windows your json string in your request should look like:

```
"{\"title\":\"Read a boo\"}"
```

I've got the same problem and it helped.

Comment: This is not a valid answer !

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the `request.json` property, try using `request.get_json(force=True)`  I would rewrite it:

```
@app.route('/todo/api/v1.0/tasks', methods=['POST'])
def create_task():
    try:
        blob = request.get_json(force=True)
    except:
        abort(400)
    if not 'title' in blob:
        abort(400)
    task = {
        'id': tasks[-1]['id'] + 1,
        'title': blob['title'],
        'description': blob.get('description', ""),
        'done': False
    }
    tasks.append(task)
    return jsonify({'task': task})
```

Comment: updated my answer - removed the `, 201` in the return statement - i think you just need to return the serialized json.

Answer (score 0):

Just put " instead of ' around the JSON string, and \ before any " inside the JSON string.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using powershell to use CURL, you need to use `curl.exe` specifically (not `curl`) add the 'dumb parsing' tag `--%`.

Then all you have to do is double quote it and escape the double quotes inside the JSON. Single quoting the outside doesn't appear to work.

```
"{\"title\":\"Read a book\"}"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
from flask import Flask, request, abort, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)
tasks = [{'id': 0}]

@app.route('/todo/api/v1.0/tasks', methods=['POST'])
def create_task():
    if not request.json or 'title' not in request.json:
        abort(400)
    task = {
        'id': tasks[-1]['id'] + 1,
        'title': request.json['title'],
        'description': request.json.get('description', ""),
        'done': False
    }
    tasks.append(task)
    response = {"task": task}
    return jsonify(response), 201

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
```

curl:

```
curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"title":"Read a book"}' http://127.0.0.1:5000/todo/api/v1.0/tasks
```

OP:

```
{
  "task": {
    "description": "", 
    "done": false, 
    "id": 1, 
    "title": "Read a book"
  }
}
```

Comment: Your solution is totally identical to mine!

Comment: yea that's what! I was not able to reproduce the error!!

Comment: @Amit Karnik This error comes when u run in windows because is is not able to understand that for what purpose that meta char ` " ` it has to use. So use  ` \" ` instead of ` " ` will work perfectly.

Comment: everyone knows it... have anything diff??

Comment: Tried this in linux running curl 7.68.0, does not work, still get same error.